# Ubuntu 12.04 Server Error when running apt-get update and upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. All went as normal but then ended up with the following error at the end.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue. I know a little bit about Ubuntu server but I am relatively new to this. Many thanks

Error below:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md1
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
W: mdadm: the array /dev/md1 with UUID c9807851:b5d3a910:3fb6082e:e5593158
W: mdadm: is currently active, but it is not listed in mdadm.conf. if
W: mdadm: it is needed for boot, then YOUR SYSTEM IS NOW UNBOOTABLE!
W: mdadm: please inspect the output of /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf, compare
W: mdadm: it to /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, and make the necessary changes.
W: mdadm: the array /dev/md3 with UUID 7495b34b:eb547028:3fb6082e:e5593158
W: mdadm: is currently active, but it is not listed in mdadm.conf. if
W: mdadm: it is needed for boot, then YOUR SYSTEM IS NOW UNBOOTABLE!
W: mdadm: please inspect the output of /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf, compare
W: mdadm: it to /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, and make the necessary changes.
Processing triggers for resolvconf ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much related to apt-get and it most likely should have finished without problems. You need to update your mdadm configuration.

Try this:

```
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Then edit /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf to remove duplicate entries and clean it up.

You can then check if it worked by re-installing your linux kernel (or you could just do update-initramfs):

```
apt-get --reinstall install linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic
```

By the way, this will only really be a problem if the raid with UUID c9807851:b5d3a910:3fb6082e:e5593158 is needed somewhere in the boot process. Otherwise your system will still boot fine. Though you may have to enter recovery console, say if /home is located on the raid and it fails to mount during boot it will drop you to a recovery login where you can manually start the raid.